# Off grid home power shutting off

Tags: power, generator

Let me start by saying thank you for reading my question. I appreciate any help offered.

My husband and I just moved to Arizona from Ohio. We purchased a modular home off grid in the mountains. This home was a rental and the owner of the property lived in Colorado. The home is powered by a generator feed by propane. Neither one of us have dealt with a system like this before. Future plans are to install solar.

The problem we are having is the generator will still be running and the power turns off in the home. It doesn't matter what is on. It could be just the refrigerator or a combination of things. It doesn't trip any breakers when it turns off. It can stay running for  hours or just minutes. It seems to stay on longer at night. This is not always the case though. We have tried turning off the breakers one by one and it still powers off.

We have replaced the circuit breaker in the generator. We replaced the main circuit breaker in the house. When we replaced the one in the home the wall with 5 outlets in the kitchen work now, which they had not previously. We had no issues with the power the rest of the day or the next. Now it is worse then ever.

The only other thing is we did an oil change (air filter and oil filter also) on the generator . We didn't have these issues before doing this. The oil was solid black. We actually did two oil changes in two days because the oil was so black after the first oil change. We have no idea when it was last done, but by the looks of things it has been awhile.

Would the oil change make the generator run more efficiently so that the house cannot handle the power supplied? The breaker box says the power supplied should not be over 100 amps. Does the breaker box need updated? We are thinking it has to be the electric, since the generator stays running.

It is frustrating since there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to the power going out. It might only go out 3 times one day and the next we can't get it to stay on.

Again, thank you for reading.  I hope I have given enough information for someone to have some idea what is wrong. If we can't figure it out, of course we will call an electrician. Right now we are over extended with the property purchase, purchase of every appliances and the long move.

Comment: Call an electrician, there are too many things that can go wrong. This is a forum for electrical engineering questions. Meaning questions related to design.

Comment: It doesn't trip any breakers, and the generator is still running ... strange? How do you get the power back on if nothing is tripped?

Comment: Yes, tell us what, if any, actions you take to make the power come back on.

Comment: what's the make and model of the generator?

Comment: Sounds like a wiring problem. Could be a loose connection directly from the generator. Secondly, the generator itself does not create amperage. It can not overpower the breaker box. The devices on your circuits put on the load and they would trip the breakers if it was a load issue. If the generator is still running, then you've got loose connections within it. You need someone to service it.

Comment: Like Tester101 asked, what kind of generator is it? Many of the "smart" generators have electronic safeties that could shut off the power without stopping the generator. If it is just a "dumb" generator, then that eliminates that possibility. It would also be good to know the answer to ArchonOSX's question, is there anything you can do to make the power come back on? If you turn the generator off and right back on, does it always temporarily fix it?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers and willingness to offer ideas. There is two toggle switches at the bottom of the breaker box marked M1 and M2. If you flip the M1 it will shut down the generator. If the power is still on in the house it doesn't do anyhing. If you turn the generator off and restart it it will also turn the power back on. I'm not sure how old the generator is. On the lid in sharpie says it had a full service on 10/06. It is a guardian by Genernic. Again thank you all for your time. It is much appreciated.

Comment: When we flip the toggle swith back up the power comes back on. Sorry left that out. I will have to look for the model number tomorrow.

Comment: Generac is a popular name brand generator so there should be plenty of available support. If needed here is their web site that offers info on their different models.  This page also has a link to help find the marking location of the Model/Serial # data.  See: http://www.generac.com/service-support/product-support-lookup/?categoryId=75bc27eb-6acd-496b-9cf5-3cd9da62443c

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't make my answer clear. The toggles  are on the bottom of the breaker box in the house. On the generator it says: model 445775.   Type 0133 01 code: 010529yg

Comment: Another plate reads item # 0041094 serial 3533414  volts 120/240  watts 8000

Comment: So is everyone thinking it might be the generator and not a problem in the house?  Again thanks everybody. For your time and knowledge. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: That's really hard to say for sure but that would be my first suspicion. Those toggles in the breaker box and whatever kind of control they use, the control wiring back to the generator, or the generator itself, could all be probable suspects. I would try to see if you could get someone familiar with generators and these controls to take a look at it because anything we say here is speculation. A good generator guy should work as long as he is good on the control side. (Some generator guys are great with the engines but have a hard time with the electronics.)

Comment: Thank you everyone for pointing us in the right direction. We have someone coming out tomorrow morning. He thinks it is probably the bushes. If not then the transfer switch. We just didn't want to sink in money we didn't have in the wrong problem. Thank you again so much!

Comment: Finally got it fixed. It was the voltage regulator. Thanks again.